# how to pass the value of checkboxes as an array from view to controller in laravel 4

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, laravel-4

I wanna know how to pass the value of several checkboxes as an array from my view to controller.
here is my code:

my view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<?php
    $count = 1;
?>

{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'action' => array('createQuizController@addQuestion'), 'id' => 'add_question')) }}

<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="table-responsive" id="question_table">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ردیف</th>
                <th>عنوان سوال</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            @foreach ($result as $quiz)
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="100px">
                        <?php echo $count++; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" width="200px">{{ $quiz->title }}</td>
                    <td align="center" width="200px"><input type="checkbox" name="select_question[]" id="counter[]" value="{{ $quiz->lesson_id }}"></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{{ Form::submit('افزودن', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}

<input type="text" id="count-checked" name="count-checked">

@stop
```

I want to post the value of checkbox ; `$quiz->lesson_id` as an array to my controller method **addQuestion**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. I believe following construct will generate array for you where each of the checkbox has correct ID set.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select_question[{{ $quiz->lesson_id }}]" id="counter_{{ $quiz->lesson_id }}">
```